# Question about virtual function workthrough works

Tags: c++

This is work through sample of my class. To be honest, I know how the virtual works with the dynamic memory. But this is pretty hard to understand for me how this workthrough works. Can you guys please let me know how it works? In the case it is calling  a.display();
foo(a);, I understand but I cannot understand how it calls function in horse when it calls animal function when it directly calls function in the horse.So I want general overview of this code, and since both are not that long, it won't take too long.
This is header.

```
// Virtual Functions
// Animal.h

#include <iostream>

class Animal{
  public: 
   virtual void display() const;
};

class Horse : public Animal {
  public:
    void display() const;
};
```

This is implementation file.

```
// Virtual Functions
// Animal.cpp

#include "Animal.h"

void Animal::display() const {
  std::cout << "Animal" << std::endl;
}

void Horse::display() const{
  std::cout << "Horse" << std::endl;
}
```

and this is the first version.

```
// Virtual Functions - Monomorphic
// h16.m.cpp

#include "Animal.h"

void foo(const Animal a){
  a.display();
}
void goo(const Animal& a){
  a.display();
}

int main(){
  Animal a;
  Horse h;
  
  a.display();
  foo(a);
  goo(a);

  h.display();
  foo(h);
  goo(h);
}
```

and this is the second one.

```
// Virtual functions - Polymorphic
// h16.cpp

#include "Animal.h"

void foo(Animal a){
  a.display();
}

void goo(Animal& a){
  a.display();
}

void foogoo(Animal& a){
  a.Animal::display();
}

int main(){
  Animal* a; // Static typing
  a = new Animal(); // Dynamic typing
  a->display();  // ani
  foo(*a); //ani
  goo(*a);  //ani
  delete a;
  a = new Horse(); // Dynamic typing
  a->display(); //horse
  foo(*a); //ani
  goo(*a); //ani
  foogoo(*a); //ani
  delete a;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: In the first one, foo(h); this output is animal. is it because it foo does not take horse object as reference? Because it does not know the address of the object?

Comment: Because passing by copy slices the `Horse` into an `Animal`, and you thus revert to `Animal`.

Comment: I have one more question. I cannot understand how   a->display(); could be horse. As I know since the function is not virtual it never allows function to use derived function.

Comment: Once a function is marked virtual in the base class, it is automatically virtual in derived classes as well. It cannot revert to non-virtual. You should also mark it `override` in subclasses so you get errors from the compiler if you ever change the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual members  have nothing to do with dynamic memory.
They are related to accessibility of class members of object of class-type B via static type A while A is one of base classes of B.

Example:

```
struct A 
{
virtual void foo();
virtual void bar();
};

struct B : A
{
void foo() override;
};

struct C : B
{
void bar() override;
};

A *ptr = new B;
A& ref = *ptr;
```

Static (known at compile time) type of object pointed by `ptr` is A. `new B` expression is evaluated while program is running. It creates object of type B, hence dynamic type of object pointed by `ptr` is B. In its stead it is possible to write this with same result:

```
B  objB;
A* ptr = &B;   // value of address of variable saved to a pointer is run-time.
A& ref = *ptr;
```

`ref` is a reference to object with dynamic type B as well even if reference got static type A.

if `foo()` wasn't declared `virtual`, `B::foo` would be a method inaccessible though  `ptr` or `ref`, because it is not present in A. But as it is, `ptr->foo()` will call B::foo().

`bar()` wasn't overridden in B , but was overridden in C. It's enough to be able to call `C::bar()` through referencing either A or B, because it was declared as virtual in A.

In your example, after  `a = new Horse();`, any calls to virtual methods of class `Animal`  accessed through derefrencing `a` are dispatched to `Horse` class if they were  overridden there, otherwise to its parents. But in function

```
void foo(const Animal a){
  a.display();
}
```

argument isn't pointer or reference. It's a new variable of type `Animal`, which would receive copy of *part* of Horse which is `Animal` object. `a.display();` here would access only `Animal::display();`

```
 Horse b;
 Animal a;
 a = b;  // it's only a part of Horse, it behaves like an Animal
```

This is exactly what happens when `foo(h)` is called. Such call includes assignment `Animal a = h` by definition of function call.

Such "cutting down" is referred as object slicing if it happens in accordance with compiler-declared operations (copy constructor or assignment). If such were redefined by user, transfer of content may be altered but destination object would retain its original static properties, including its original virtual table (a list of declared virtual members).

It is important to remember that class that got a base class, contains an object of base class. It is said that base class is a ***sub-object*** of derived class, just like  any member declared withing Derived class.

Comment: In the first one, foo(h); this output is animal. is it because it foo does not take horse object as reference? Because it does not know the address of the object?

Comment: @QuestionMaker yeah, you can fthink of it as not receiving address of Horse.  that `foo()` received a copy of `Animal` object stored in `Horse`, see my edit.